# Restoring Postgres database without pg dump?

Tags: postgresql, database-restore

I have a postgre database DATA1 in table space location D:\tbl_DATA1. We use OS backup restore tool copy the the D:\tbl_DATA1 to a target machine C:\tbl_DATA1. Is it possible for recreate the database from this folder in the second mahcine?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Is it a tablespace? or a whole PostgreSql database? Does it contain the directories `pg_clog`, `pg_xlog`, and `global`? If so, you can just copy it and start PostgreSQL from it. If not, you're boned because a tablespace is pretty meaningless without the shared catalogs, transaction commit logs, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-file.html

> An alternative backup strategy is to directly copy the files that
>   PostgreSQL uses to store the data in the database

and later two restrictions mentionned

- The database server must be shut down in order to get a usable backup.
- You should resotore the whole PGDATA direcotory, not the certain individual tables or databases from their respective files or directories.

So **yes** - it is a common practice to shutdown the PostgreSQL, copy PGDATA directory to other machine and start Postgres in order to get the cluser copy. But it is done cluster level - not tablespace as you mention or database - **the whole data_directory** should be copied.

So **no** - copying the tablespace directory and trying to hack the db to add a tablespace will fail.